# How to migrate customer data from magento 1.9 to 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, migration

How to migrate customer data from magento 1.9 to 2?

Comment: I hope its done and if not then I will post answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default Magento 2 Migration tool.

Guide Link : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

Install tool for a migration :
https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/

**OR**

UberTheme migration tool.

This is easier way to migrate Magento 1.9.X to Magento 2.X.X

Guide Link : 
https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-pro-release/

Install tool for a migration :
https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration/releases/tag/Version0.1.0

Comment: with out install tool can not do this one?.. in csv import any possible way ..

Comment: i ask without tool install it not possibility ?.

Comment: First of all you have to export magento 1.9.X CSV then download magento 2 demo export CSV. Create format like magento 2 .But this is way is too much time taking and Not easy .Because for attribute and some other filed you have to merge and all that.so batter way it migrate date using tool.

Comment: ok i try to this tool UberTheme Migration tool.

Comment: this tool is the pro version only to migrate customer option..

Comment: Batter way is that, You just migrant all data and then export data of customer, then import into your website .